# R-Squared is nan ml.net

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm trying to create a tool for student performance prediction, but when I'm evaluating my model, I'm getting NaN for

```
private RegressionMetrics EvaluateModel(IDataView data)
{
     var transformSet = GetModel().Transform(data);
     var metrics = _context.Regression.Evaluate(transformSet);
     return metrics;
}

var metrics = EvaluateModel(dataView);
```

I'm getting values for MeanAbsoluteError or LossFunction, everything else but RSquared, any idea why?

Comment: Just curious, how many rows are in your training data set?

Comment: I also saw this issue, some time the loading data success and some times I see nan value, I can't tell why.